# How To Set Text In An EditText with Sting object

Tags: java, android, android-edittext

I have a String object and I would like to set the text in a EditText object.  Can this be done

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
myEditText.setText("some text")
```

That method is inherited from TextView

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html

Answer (score 2):

Yes, this can be done.

```
editText.setText(string);
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't really know how you mean. It looks a bit trivial..

Is this what you're looking for?

```
editTextObject.setText(stringObject.text);
```

If not please be more precise.